# Why does :before element break layout?

Tags: html, css

I want to display some background images along with some text. Everything should be divided by a `|` (pipe) to separate the elements.

The pipe is included with an `:before` selector with the pipe as content.
However it seems that this breaks the layout as the background images are now not longer on the same line as the text. If I remove the content completely it works as expected.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

I've created a small [Fiddle as example](https://jsfiddle.net/1cbeyn84/).

Comment: your title could have been same as "help me".. it's very very vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout uses `float: left` so `:before` should follow the same rule. For example:

```
.list-piped:before {
    display: block; /* fix */
    float: left; /* fix */
    content: "|"; /* This breaks the layout */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/infous/1cbeyn84/4/

BTW, Manoj Kumar below has described the real problem. My answer is a possible solution because `float: left` as well as `position: absolute` has its own flow.

Answer (score 3):

**Why does this happen?**

Check out this [Image](https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/multiplecanvases.jpg). Technically `::before` is part of `li(.list-piped)` and takes up the whole width, pushing the child items(icons) to bottom.

**How to fix?**

Apply `::before` to child elements or use `position: absolute` to the current code.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/1cbeyn84/2/)

Comment: Your answer is more clear, I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, as far as OP gets the reasoning.